# Dead simple cross-domain php script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cross-domain

I'm looking for a simple script in which I can do something like this

```
$.getScript('fetcher.php?url=' + escape('http://www.google.com') + '&callback=console.log');
```

The response should be **one** really long line that looks like this:

```
console.log({responseText: '<!doctype html><html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>Google</title><script>windo...'})
```

It shouldn't be more than 10 lines of code and there's no way it doesn't already exist.

I'm using php in XAMPP and am just using it to build a database so I don't need any frills included (no get vs post, no data included) just `file_get_contents` and `$_GET`. Of course I would still like to encoded the url

Comment: Do you limit the characters per line? If dont, I can write it in 1 line :D

Comment: @thaolt: How about a readable script, just not too intense of the options

Comment: This link describes this issue pretty well: http://bit.ly/eDLd4S

Comment: @SeanKinsey: I was asking because I assumed this already existed and didn't want to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this , updated

```
<?php
    // fetcher.php
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $callback = $_GET['callback'];
    $read = file_get_contents($url);
    $read = addslashes(htmlspecialchars(str_replace("\n","\\n",$read)));
?>
<script>
    <?php echo $callback ?>({responseText: '<?php echo $read; ?>'});
</script>
```

Comment: I want to preserve `'\n'`(linebreaks in the html) to become `'\\n'` (in the response) so that in the string it's a newline. Also I wan to be able to use escaped url

Comment: I didnt test this yet, did you try the code of dakis, Ill test it out

Comment: I didn't bother, I don't have curl

Comment: ok, ill try to help you out,str_replace("\n","\\n".. seems doesnt work

Comment: it run ok now, but I dont know if it fits your need

Answer (score 0):

**fetcher.php**

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_GET['url']);
    echo curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

**javascript**

```
$.get("fetcher.php", {url: "http://www.google.com/"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```